# What did I do wrong on setting up MvvmCross 6.0?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am new to MvvmCross 6.0 and Xamarin.

I am trying to follow the [tutorial here that for MvvmCrosss 5.5](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/12/27/Getting-Started-MvvmCross-with-Xamarin-Forms-(Part-2).aspx)

I followed the explanation,

1. Created App.xaml as MvxFormsApplication

> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <core:MvxFormsApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
>              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
>              xmlns:core="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Core;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
>              x:Class="App3.App">
> </core:MvxFormsApplication>
> ```

2. CoreApp.cs as MvxApplication and runs             RegisterAppStart(); in my overrided Initialize()

> ```
> public class CoreApp : MvxApplication
>     {
>
>         public override void Initialize()
>         {
>             CreatableTypes()
>                 .EndingWith("Service")
>                 .AsInterfaces()
>                 .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
>
>             CreatableTypes()
>                 .EndingWith("Client")
>                 .AsInterfaces()
>                 .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
>
>             // register the appstart object
>             RegisterAppStart<MainPageViewModel>();
>         }
>     }
> ```

3. MainPageViewModel to inherited MvxViewModel

> ```
> public class MainPageViewModel : MvxViewModel
>     {
>     }
> ```

4. View that created as MvxContentPage with type MainPageViewModel

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

5. Removed MainActivity and created a file called MainApplication.cs as follow

> ```
> [Activity(Label = "MvvmcrossGettingStarted", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,
> ```
>
> ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize |
>   ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
>           public class MainActivity : MvxFormsAppCompatActivity
>           {
>               protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
>               {
>                   TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
>                   ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
>
> ```
>             base.OnCreate(bundle);
>
>             var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
>             startup.Start();
>             InitializeForms(bundle);
>
>         }
>     }
>
>
>     public class Setup : MvxFormsAndroidSetup
>     {
>         public Setup():base()
>         {
>
>         }
>
>         protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies => new List<Assembly>(base.AndroidViewAssemblies
>             .Union(new[] { typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly })
>             .Except(new[] { this.GetType().Assembly })
>         );
>
>         protected override Application CreateFormsApplication()
>         {
>             return new App();
>         }
>
>
>         protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp() => new CoreApp();
>     }
> ```

However what I started the app, its gives me null exception saying "bundle" parameter is null in OnCreated method.

P.S.  The tutorial mention to create the Setup.cs, but I have no idea how does that Setup.cs being run by the code.... I see no where that is referencing it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're looking at the version 5.5 tutorial while working with v 6.0. Try following [step by step guide](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post-2018-04-13-mvx0f-a-first-mvvmcross-application-mvx1-days-of-mvvmcross-aspx/), from same author, but for version 6.0

You might also want to download Nick's sample, from his [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nickrandolph/MvxPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/Mvx-00-FirstDemo), to check how things work.

Comment: Thanks @DamirBeylkhanov. Nick has recently updated his blog and might have not migrated his blog links properly. I've edited my answer with new link